# Could "Rather = Little bit" be true?

Tags: synonyms

After reading [usage-and-meaning-of-the-word-rather](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85441/usage-and-meaning-of-the-word-rather), I had a thought if I could replace rather with "little bit" (it's still in doubt by the way).

What I've known so far (correct me if I'm wrong), rather is used to compare different things like:

> it's rather blue than green

or in other words

> it's more blue than green.

That's what I know. I tried to find some sentences using "rather" and replaced it with "little bit". Let's see these examples:

> It was a *rather* difficult question. **->** It was a *little bit*
> difficult question.
>
> I've always *rather* liked Charlie. **->** I've always *little bit*
> liked Charlie.
>
> The rules are *rather* complicated. **->** The rules are *little bit*
> complicated.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Check the answers to the question you linked again, they basically answer your question here as well.

Comment: Would you rather be attacked by a shark or a lion?

Comment: I would interpret "I've always rather liked Charlie" to mean "I've always liked Charlie more than I like most people", and "That concerto is rather beautiful" as ""That concerto is very beautiful". I think this is British understatement.

Comment: A rather difficult question and rather complicated rules are both more than just a little bit. Rather can be seen as *a little bit* more than 50%. You can use rather to soften (from 100%) as well as intensify. *Rather cheeky* softens the judgment of nerviness from cheeky to kinda cheeky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at two different meanings of *rather.*

In 'It's rather blue than green', *rather* means *instead of, as opposed to.* The object can better be described as blue than as green.

In your other sentences, *rather* means *somewhat, to a certain extent.* You could say "The rules are **a** [little] bit complicated." (*A bit* is more usual than *a little bit*.)

"The question was a [little] bit difficult" is possible, but we wouldn't say "It was a bit difficult question."

We wouldn't say "I've always [a] little bit liked Charlie", and "I like Charlie a little bit" sounds as though you don't really like him much at all. "I rather like" sounds much more positive.

Comment: [Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rather+blue+than+green%2Cblue+rather+than+green&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3): 'blue rather than green'.

Answer (score -1):

Oxford dictionary online gives definition:[rather] "...used to mean ‘fairly’ or ‘to some degree’, often when you are disappointed, surprised or expressing slight criticism."

You have the "little bit" right; however, don't leave out connotation of disappointment, surprise, or expression of criticism in your use of "rather."